# Using HAProxy on a single server

Tags: apache-2.4, haproxy

I'm trying to make my web app faster and planning to install HAProxy on same droplet.

My current setup is :
Laravel on Apache, MySQL, PHP 5.5.9, OpCache, PageSpeedMod.

Installing and using HAProxy will improve my performance (speed or server load) ?

- Can it improve performance as it acts as reverse proxy in my Apache setup? Is it worth it?
- I have single MySQL server running on same droplet with 100x reads compared to writes. Can HAProxy affect or improve anything on MySQL side ?

I'm new to HAProxy and server performance optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not, because it merely acts as a load balancer and you have nothing to load balance.

Use nginx with caching, that will improve things. To get even better results, get rid of Apache completely and use nginx only.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried nginx. one of the reason I moved back to Apache was pagespeed module setup documentation is screwed up. DO, Linode, official docs are broken for the latest version. I have 50% faster with Pagespeed mod.

Comment: Then hire someone to do it for you :). There is a number of people using it so it works.

Comment: I usually try to learn and apply on my own so that I can fix any issues later and also can apply the implementation in the future :)